# Show that $\mathcal{J}=\{[a, a+1) \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ generates the Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Problem** Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{J})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mathcal{J}=\{[a, a+1) \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

---

I'm using the following lemma:
Let $G,G´\subset P(X)$. $\sigma (G) = \sigma (G´) \iff G \subset \sigma (G´) \: \wedge \: G´\subset \sigma (G)$.

---

*My solution*

$\mathcal{J} \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$: It is known that the sets of half-open rectangles $\mathscr{J}=\{ \left[ b,c \right):b<c \in \mathbb{R} \}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ generates the Borel set on $\mathbb{R}$. So $\mathcal{J} \subset \mathscr{J} \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \implies \mathcal{J} \subset \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ $\square$.

$\mathscr{J}\subset\sigma(\mathcal{J})$: My idea is that I will like to construct this type of interval $\left[ b,c \right),b<c \in \mathbb{R}$ using $ \left[ a,a+1 \right),a \in \mathbb{R}$ using all the set operations available for which a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under. From $ \left[ a,a+1 \right),a \in \mathbb{R}$ I find it hard to construct an interval with an arbitrary right interval point instead of $a+1$.
Hints and help are welcome.

Comment: BTW. When applying a LaTex "function"  like \mathcal or \cos or \bar or \sqrt to a single key-stroke, you do not need brace-brackets. Just leave a single space after the function's name.  E.g. \mathcal B(\mathbb R). I also found that \Bbb is identical to \mathbb .

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I know, but it makes the "source code" more readable for me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

I leave some details to the OP

- First notice that the sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$ generated by the intervals $[a,a+1)$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is contained in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (why?)
- Notice that dir any $b\in\mathbb{R}$, $(-\infty,b)=\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}[b-n,b-n+1)$ is in $\mathcal{A}$.
- Then, for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$,  $(-\infty,a]=\bigcap^\infty_{k=1}(-\infty,a+\tfrac{1}{k})$ is also in $\mathcal{A}$. Consequently, $\mathbb{R}\setminus(-\infty,a]=(a,\infty)$ is in $\mathcal{A}$. This means that $(a, b)=(a,\infty)\cap(-\infty,b)$, for all $a<b$, is in $\mathcal{A}$.
- Thus $\mathcal{A}$ contains all open intervals (finite and infinite) and so all open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ (every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the countable union of disjoint open intervals.
- So $\mathcal{A}$ and the Borel sigma algebra are the same.

Comment: Alright, I can probably take it from here.
I wonder whether there is a more standard method of doing these types of problems?

Comment: Tthis and the other solution is  the "standard" method whose strategy boils down  to showing that all open intervals can be generated though countable operations of unions, intersections and complementations, of the sets given as generators.

Comment: Alright. I will try to keep that in mind. I have a hard time constructing the sets and intervals. It is probably just trying.

Comment: @Xenusi: There are many ways to do it, mine I think was direct. One can also notice that $[a,a+h)=[a+h-1,a+h)\cap[a,a+1)$ for all $0<h<1$. Then all left-closed intervals of integer length as well as of integer plus fractional length are in $\mathcal{A}$. The rest is then standard.

Comment: Alright, I will try to give the problem another (at least) try.

Comment: Regard 3rd point in your answer.

How is $(-\infty, a]=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-\infty, a+\frac{1}{k}\right)$ in $\mathcal{A}$ ? I can not see how one could write them in the form of $[a,a+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

For $a<b$ with $b-a\leq1$, we have $[a,b)=[a,a+1)\setminus[b,b+1)\in\sigma(\mathcal{J})$.
Note that every interval of the form $[a,b)$ can be written as finite
union of intervals of the form $[c,d)$ with $d-c\leq1$. Therefore
$[a,b)\in\sigma(\mathcal{J})$. Next, $(a,b)=\cap_{n}[a+\frac{1}{n},b)\in\sigma(\mathcal{J})$.
Since every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of open
intervals, $\sigma(\mathcal{J})$ contains every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
It follows that $\sigma(\mathcal{J})\supseteq\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
The reverse inclusion is trivial.

Comment: I think that you have, accidentally, read the intervals wrong.

Comment: Yes. Typo. Please replace "(" by "[" and "]" by ")". However, the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=\mathcal J$ and let $G'$ be the set of bounded open intervals.  I assume you know that $\sigma(G')=\mathcal B(\Bbb R).$

1.If $g'=(x,y)\in G'$ with $y>x+1$ then $g'=\cup \{[z,z+1): z\in \Bbb Q\cap (x,y-1]\}\in \sigma (G).$

2. If $g'=(x,y)\in G'$ with $y\le x+1$ then $(y-2,y)$ and $(x,x+2)$ both belong to $\sigma (G)$ by 1. So $g'=(y-2,y)\cap (x,x+2)\in \sigma (G).$

Therefore $G'\subset \sigma (G).$