# If $\{a<f<b\} $ is measurable, for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

let $f:E\to \mathbb{R} $ If $\{a<f<b\} $ is measurable, for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$  then $f$ is measurable.

We can write the set $\{a<f<b\} =\{f>a\}\cap  \{f<b\}$ but I don't see how we can get that
$\{f>a\}$ is  measurable for every  $a\in \mathbb{R}$

Any hints  ?

Comment: $\{f>a\}=\bigcup_{n\geq1}\{a<f<a+n\}$

Comment: ooh that's  clever ! I would never figure , thanks.

Comment: There are several versions of this problem already discussed in MSE. For example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4139863/121671). The general strategy is to use countable unions, intersections and/or complementation to build canonical sets.