# Prove that $\{(b,\infty]: b\in R\}$ generates $\mathcal{B}_{\overline R}$

Tags: measure-theory

I tried proving the title of the question above/claim below. I'm wondering if my proof is correct and if my lemma is correct. I can provide my proof of the lemma if you want.

*Claim.* Let $\mathcal{E} = \{(b,\infty]:b\in R\}$. Then $\mathcal{E}$ generates $\mathcal{B}_{\overline R}$. Here, $\mathcal{B}_{\overline R}$ is the Borel sigma-algebra on the extended real line,  $\mathcal{B}_{\overline R} =\{E\in\mathcal{P}(\overline R): E \cap R \in \mathcal{B}\}$, with $\mathcal{B}$ being the Borel sets.

*Proof*. We need to prove that $\mathcal{B}_{\overline R} = \sigma(\mathcal{E})$.

$\subseteq$: Suppose $E$ is in the LHS. Then $E$ is a subset of $\overline R$ and $E\cap R$ is a Borel set. Letting $\mathcal{F}$ be a sigma-algebra on $\overline R$ containing $\mathcal{E}$, we need to show that $E$ is in $\mathcal{F}$. In the case that $E$ does not contain $-\infty$ or $\infty$, $E$ is a subset of $R$ and so $E = E\cap R$, implying that $E$ is a Borel set. By the lemma below, the Borel sets are contained in $\mathcal{F}$, and so $E$ is too.

---

**Lemma:** Let $X$ be a subset of $Y$ and suppose $\mathcal{I}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. If $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma-algebra on $Y$ containing $X$ and every set of $\mathcal{I}$, then $\sigma_X(\mathcal{I}) \subseteq \mathcal{F}$.

**Applying this to our situation**: Let $X:= R$, $Y:= \overline R$, $\mathcal{I}:= \{(b,\infty):b\in R\}$ (which generates the Borel sets), and $\mathcal{A} := \mathcal{F}$ from the display above. One easily shows that $\mathcal{I}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ by first proving that $\mathcal{F}$ contains $\{\infty\}$ using closedness under countable intersections. Then one uses this to go on to show that it also contains $R$ using closedness under countable unions. Now it follows that $\sigma_R(\mathcal{I}) = \mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ as claimed.

---

Continuing with our proof, in the case that $E$ contains $-\infty$ or $\infty$, suppose first that only $-\infty$ is in $E$. The two other cases are shown analogously. We can then write $E = (E\cap R)\cup\{-\infty\}$ and from hypothesis and lemma, we know that the former is in $\mathcal{F}$. To see that the latter is also in $\mathcal{F}$, we note that for any $n$, $[-\infty,-n] = (-n,\infty]^c\in\mathcal{F}$. Hence, writing $\{-\infty\} = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-\infty,-n]$, it follows that $\{-\infty\}\in\mathcal{F}$. QED

$\supseteq$: This is easier. Suppose $E$ is in the RHS. Then $E$ is in every sigma-algebra on $\overline R$ containing $\mathcal{E}$. Now $\mathcal{B}_{\overline R}$ in particular is a sigma-algebra on $\overline R$ and it also contains $\mathcal{E}$ (to see this, note that given any real number $b$ one has $(b,\infty]\cap R = (b,\infty)$ which is in $\mathcal{B}$). Hence $E$ is in $\mathcal{B}_{\overline R}$. QED

Comment: There are several variatiation to this problem. (for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3830910/121671), The key is to show that the sets $(a,b)$ are in $\mathscr{B}$ which is done by complements to se that sets of the form $(-\infty,b)$ are in $\mathscr{B}$, intersections to get sets os the form $(a,b]$ and countable unions to get sets of the form $(a,b)$

Comment: @OliverDíaz I'm okay with the various generators of $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I've clarified how I use my lemma in order to make reading easier. Check the proof if you like! If you don't, that's okay too, of course.